# How do I search in Flutter DropDown button

Tags: dart, flutter, filtering, dropdown

I have a list of the countries name in local json. I can load my local json and assign to **DropDown button**. there is a 193 countries  in json file as ex. shown below. If I want to select United State, user have to scroll all the way down.  How can enter a countries name such as; if I user enter U or u the dropdown can makes quick filtering and list all the countries that starts with U such as United State. **How do I search in Flutter DropDownbutton items**?

```json
{
    "country": [
        {
            "countryCode": "AD",
            "countryName": "Andorra",
            "currencyCode": "EUR",
            "isoNumeric": "020"
        },
        {
            "countryCode": "AE",
            "countryName": "United Arab Emirates",
            "currencyCode": "AED",
            "isoNumeric": "784"
        },
        {
            "countryCode": "AF",
            "countryName": "Afghanistan",
            "currencyCode": "AFN",
            "isoNumeric": "004"
        },
        //...
    ]
}
```

Comment: you can use dropdown_search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381692/how-can-i-search-item-from-searchable-dropdown-per-name-instead-of-per-id

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use searchable_dropdown package instead: 
https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

And here is my example code
[searchable_dropdown dont work with class list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60025636/searchable-dropdown-dont-work-with-class-list)

Make sure that you put the following if you use a class list like my example

```
  @override
  String toString() {
    return this.key;
  }
```

Comment: this package gives an error subhead not found.

Answer (score 5):

One way is to use a `TextEditingController` to filter your `ListView` like this:

```
class YourPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => YourPageState();
}

class YourPageState extends State<YourPage> {
  List<Country> countries = new List<Country>();
  TextEditingController controller = new TextEditingController();
  String filter;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //fill countries with objects
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        filter = controller.text;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    controller.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: new Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0, left: 16.0, right: 16.0),
                child: new TextField(
                  style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.black),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: new Icon(Icons.search),
                    suffixIcon: new IconButton(
                      icon: new Icon(Icons.close),
                      onPressed: () {
                        controller.clear();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
                      },
                    ),
                    hintText: "Search...",
                  ),
                  controller: controller,
                )),
            new Expanded(
              child: new Padding(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                  child: _buildListView()),
            )
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: countries.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if (filter == null || filter == "") {
            return _buildRow(countries[index]);
          } else {
            if (countries[index].countryName
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(filter.toLowerCase())) {
              return _buildRow(countries[index]);
            } else {
              return new Container();
            }
          }
        });
  }

  Widget _buildRow(Country c) {
    return new ListTile(
        title: new Text(
          c.countryName,
        ),
        subtitle: new Text(
          c.countryCode,
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: SnakeyHips you misunderstood my question. My dropdown button inside a ListView, and I assign my data to my dropdown button. I am looking way so I can search or filter the dropdown button with user interaction.

Comment: @Nick SnakeyHips is right. You have to use a ListView with TextField column widget in a dialog instead of the drop down. In fact the drop down is bad choice for big lists like country list. I mean it's not html.

Comment: This is great solution, however flutter doesn't load all the countries at once, so we cannot filter for mid to low level records. A better solution is to have another filtered list of countries and fill/clear this according to filter and we can put this code directly in the listener.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[dropdown_search](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_search)** package like below.

```dart
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';

DropdownSearch<String>(
    popupProps: PopupProps.menu(
        showSearchBox: true,
        showSelectedItems: true,
        disabledItemFn: (String s) => s.startsWith('I'),
    ),
    items: ["Brazil", "Italia (Disabled)", "Tunisia", 'Canada'],
    dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
        dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
            labelText: "Menu mode",
            hintText: "country in menu mode",
        ),
    ),
    onChanged: print,
    selectedItem: "Brazil",
)
```

Make sure you have set `showSearchBox` attribute under `popupProps`. This attribute is not yet mentioned in the documentation. See [PopupProps source code](https://github.com/salim-lachdhaf/searchable_dropdown/blob/master/lib/src/properties/popup_props.dart) for more attributes.

Comment: Hi @ruwan800, I am using this `dropdownSearch` widget and showing a simple list, but I want to show a section list in `dropdownSearch` widget, is it possible to show a section list?

Comment: I don't get what do meant by section list? Do you need to add separators in between some list items?

Comment: No, I was trying to show Items below a particular section, for ex: Section1: Item1, Item2, Item3, below the section in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Use textfield_search: ^0.8.0 [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/textfield_search) [view sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q95BD.png)

```
            TextFieldSearch(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Search",
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.black45,
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
              ),
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
            ),
            initialList: constants.VEHICLELIST,
            label: "label",
            controller: selectedVehicle),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old I think, as now using just the included material package and utilizing the DropDownMenu widget works.
You use the `enableFilter: True`  property to enable the manual search.
If you somehow click the widget and it doesn't allow you to type for searching, then adding the property `requestFocusOnTap: true` helps especially in **ListViews** / **ListTiles** / **Scrollables Cards**

```
DropdownMenu<CountryEntity>(
        controller: countryController,
        label: const Text('Country'),
        width: 300,
        dropdownMenuEntries: countryEntities,
        enableFilter: true,
        menuStyle: const MenuStyle(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            maximumSize:
                MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size.fromHeight(Sizes.p124)),),
        requestFocusOnTap: true,
        onSelected: (country) {
          setState(() {
            selectedCountryId = country;
          });
        },
      );
```