# How can I search item from Searchable Dropdown per Name instead of per Id?

Tags: flutter

How can I search item from Searchable Dropdown per Name instead of per Id ?

```
SearchableDropdown(items:_vagasDisponiveis.map((item) {
            return new DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(item.v_n),
              value: item.v_id
            );
          }
        ).toList(),
    isExpanded: true,
    value: vaga_id,
    isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
    searchHint: new Text('Select ', style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
    onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
        vaga_id = value;
    });
  },
)
```

Example: https://pub.dev/packages/searchable_dropdown

Comment: Hello Ryan, Welcome to StackOverflow ? I have modified title and formatted your code in code bloc. I advise you, next time to format your code like this. Can you check if the new title is conform to what you have written previously. Can you also give more explanations on your code so that other users understand what you have already tried ? Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to overwrite your class's `toString()` so it can search both id and name 
because `SearchableDropdown`'s source code use `item.value.toString()` 
when you pass class name it will become `I/flutter ( 7352): Instance of 'VagasDisponivei'` 
you can copy paste run full code below

code snippet

```
class VagasDisponivei {
  String v_n;
  String v_id;

  VagasDisponivei({this.v_n, this.v_id});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${v_n} ${v_id}';
  }
}

SearchableDropdown(
              items: _vagasDisponiveis.map((item) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<VagasDisponivei>(
                    child: Text(item.v_n), value: item);
              }).toList(),
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectedValue,
              isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
              searchHint: new Text(
                'Select ',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value;
                  print(selectedValue);
                });
              },
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:searchable_dropdown/searchable_dropdown.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class VagasDisponivei {
  String v_n;
  String v_id;

  VagasDisponivei({this.v_n, this.v_id});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${v_n} ${v_id}';
  }
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  List<VagasDisponivei> _vagasDisponiveis;
  String vaga_name;
  VagasDisponivei selectedValue;
  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _vagasDisponiveis = [
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "1", v_n: "abc"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "2", v_n: "def"),
      VagasDisponivei(v_id: "3", v_n: "dgg"),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SearchableDropdown(
              items: _vagasDisponiveis.map((item) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<VagasDisponivei>(
                    child: Text(item.v_n), value: item);
              }).toList(),
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectedValue,
              isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
              searchHint: new Text(
                'Select ',
                style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  selectedValue = value;
                  print(selectedValue);
                });
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

code snippet of SearchableDropdown

```
if(widget.isCaseSensitiveSearch){
        print(item.value.toString());
        isContains = item.value.toString().contains(keyword);
      }
```

Comment: thanks for answering it is working but when i try to send it get all data is it possible to keep searching by name and send by id?

Comment: I have answered your second post question. you can see may post, glad to help, please mark this as answer if it help you. thanks.

Comment: Thank you @chunhunghan :) This just helped me a ton!

Answer (score 1):

i am using dropdown_search: ^0.4.8

here is my code which finds item with there name and in value it sets their id.

```
import 'package:dropdown_search/dropdown_search.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  KeyValueModel selectedValue;
  String hello;
  TextEditingController v = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              DropdownSearch<KeyValueModel>(
                  mode: Mode.DIALOG,
                  showSelectedItem:false,
                  items: [KeyValueModel(itemId: "123",itemName: "mohit"),KeyValueModel(itemId: "124",itemName: "hello"),KeyValueModel(itemId: "125",itemName: "hey")],
                  itemAsString: (KeyValueModel u) => u.itemName,
                  hint: "select",
                  onChanged: (value){
                    v.text = value.itemId.toString();
                    print(value.itemId);
                  },
                  showSearchBox: true,
                  filterFn: (instance, filter){
                    if(instance.itemName.contains(filter)){
                      print(filter);
                      return true;
                    }
                    else{
                      return false;
                    }
                  },
                  popupItemBuilder: (context,KeyValueModel item,bool isSelected){
                    return Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                      decoration: !isSelected
                          ? null
                          : BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(item.itemName),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                 ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class KeyValueModel{
  String itemName;
  String itemId;
  KeyValueModel({this.itemName,this.itemId});
}
```

Comment: In version 5.0.6 up, you need to add `showSearchBox` attribute under `popupProps` attribute. Create `PopupProp` instance using `PopupProps.menu` method.