# searchable_dropdown dont work with class list

Tags: flutter, dropdown, searchable

I Implemented a flutter dropdown menu using searchable_dropdown 1.1.0 package,, 
I tested with my class list, and I found that the search TextField box dont work with my list of class.
 I want that my dropdown search box works when I search for a value in both strings/intgers in my list.

for example: I want that when I type number 1 or key 1 it should show me the item I searched for

I wonder how to fix this problem? 
Thanks for help

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:searchable_dropdown/searchable_dropdown.dart';

get_list(){
  List<KeyValueModel> datas = [
    KeyValueModel(key: "Key 1", value: "Value 1"),
    KeyValueModel(key: "Key 2", value: "Value 2"),
    KeyValueModel(key: "Key 3", value: "Value 3"),
    KeyValueModel(key: "Key 4", value: "Value 4"),
    KeyValueModel(key: "Key 5", value: "Value 5"),
  ];
  return datas;
}
//Create a Model class to hold key-value pair data
class KeyValueModel {
  String key;
  String value;

  KeyValueModel({this.key, this.value});
}


class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  TestState createState() {
    return new TestState();
  }
}
class TestState extends State<Test> {

  List listan = get_list();

  KeyValueModel _selectedValue = KeyValueModel(key: "0", value: "value");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Key value Pair - DropdownButton'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            SearchableDropdown<KeyValueModel>(
        isCaseSensitiveSearch: true,
              items: listan
                  .map((data) => DropdownMenuItem<KeyValueModel>(
                child: Text(data.key),
                value: data,
              )).toList(),
              onChanged: (KeyValueModel value) {
                setState(() => _selectedValue = value);
              },
              hint: Text('Select Key'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 25.0,
            ),
            Text(_selectedValue.value),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit code from the package.

```
...

if(widget.isCaseSensitiveSearch){
   isContains = item.value.toString().contains(keyword);
}
else{
   isContains = item.value.toString().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toLowerCase());
}

...
```

It calls `toString()` on the `value`. In your case `value` is type of `KeyValueModel` and doesn't have an overriden `toString()` method. So it returns `Instance of KeyValueModel` instead of `Key 1` or such.

Here is the class that returns the `key` when `toString()` method called.

```
class KeyValueModel {
  String key;
  String value;

  KeyValueModel({this.key, this.value});

  @override
  String toString() {
    return key;
  }
}
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. But there is a problem with capital letters, Key starts with K capital letter.. When I search with small k letter dose not work. How to make the search works small letters too ?

Comment: You set it yourself on your widget tree by declaring `isCaseSensitiveSearch: true`. Make it false.

Comment: @mike is there a way to automatically deselect the item on dropdown opens instead of clicking the clear button in this plugin?

Comment: @BLB how do you mean exactly?

Comment: @mike never mind. This fixed everything. Thank you