# dropdown_button2 Search is Not Working with Class List

Tags: flutter, dropdown, searchable

I have a dropdown button which I implemented using `dropdown_button2 1.9.2`.

I want to make the dropdown_button ***searchable***.

I tried implementing it with my custom class but it won't work.

I have tried overriding the `toString method` of my class (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60025923/7113369)) but it still won't work.

Please any fix or am I doing something wrong here?

This is the dropdown button

[image]

This is what it does when I try searching for an item in the dropdown.
[image]

This is my full code:

```
import 'package:dropdown_button2/dropdown_button2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs, sort_constructors_first
class MyDropDownItems {
  MyDropDownItems({
    required this.text,
    required this.value,
  });

  String text;
  String value;

  @override
  String toString() {
    return value;
  }
}

class MoodScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MoodScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<MoodScreen> createState() => _MoodScreenState();
}

class _MoodScreenState extends State<MoodScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  // Initial Selected Value
  String _dropdownvalue = ' ';

  final _dropDownItems = [
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Select Mood", value: " "),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 1", value: "happy"),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 2", value: "Sad"),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 3", value: "Confused"),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 4", value: "Lonely"),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 5", value: "Excited"),
    MyDropDownItems(text: "Mood 6", value: "Wealthy"),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 300,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 12,
                vertical: 4,
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
              ),
              child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                child: DropdownButton2(
                  searchController: _textEditingController,
                  searchInnerWidget: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      top: 8,
                      bottom: 4,
                      right: 8,
                      left: 8,
                    ),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _textEditingController,
                      decoration: const InputDecoration(
                        isDense: true,
                        hintText: 'Select mood...',
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10,
                          vertical: 8,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
                    return (item.value.toString().contains(searchValue));
                  },
                  onMenuStateChange: (isOpen) {
                    if (!isOpen) {
                      _textEditingController.clear();
                    }
                  },
                  value: _dropdownvalue,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  iconSize: 36,
                  iconEnabledColor: Colors.green,
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_drop_down_circle,
                  ),
                  items: _dropDownItems.map((MyDropDownItems networkNumbers) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: networkNumbers.value,
                      child: Text(networkNumbers.text),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      _dropdownvalue = value!;
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text("The mood is: $_dropdownvalue"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to search by the display name, then `searchMatchFn` should be as following

```
searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
    final myItem = _dropDownItems.firstWhere((element) => element.value == item.value);
    return myItem.text.contains(searchValue);
}
```

or if you need search based on value and text, then

```
searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
    final myItem = _dropDownItems.firstWhere((element) => element.value == item.value);
    return myItem.text.contains(searchValue) || item.value.toString().contains(searchValue);
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Did you try the code? Did it work for you?

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time to answer my question. 

I tried the code again and it worked. 

However, it's case-sensitive.

So, if I search for "Mood" in the textFormfirld, it will show. 

But if I search for "mood", it won't show because of the lowercase. 

Is there a trick for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
searchMatchFn: (item, searchValue) {
    final myItem = _dropDownItems.firstWhere((element) => element.value == item.value);
    return myItem.text.toLowerCase().contains(searchValue.toLowerCase()) || item.value.toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchValue.toLowerCase());
}
```

That will make it case insensetive

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**